# Security group blocking by IP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've an application in VPC, with Autoscaling Group and Application Load Balancer. Only web tier should access RDS DB, Which IP should I block in security group either VPC CIDR block or Autoscaling Group or Application Load Balancer?

Comment: Security group rules don't block traffic; they allow traffic. Also, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Answer (score 2):

By defauilt a security group allows nothing, so all IPs are block. You don't add rules in order to "block" IPs, you add rules in order to allow traffic. In your instance you need to add a rule in the RDS DB's security group to allow traffic from the EC2 servers in the auto-scaling group. The best way to do this is to specify the security group the EC2 instances belong to as the source, instead of trying to add a specific list of IPs or CIDR block.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended method is to have **three security groups**:

- **Load Balancer security group (ELB-SG):** This security group defines allowed inbound traffic to the Load Balancer, typically port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). The security group should be associated with the Load Balancer.
- **App security group (App-SG):** This should permit inbound connections (eg port 80) from ELB-SG. It should refer to the load balancer's security group rather than the load balancer itself. The security group should be associated with the Auto Scaling group, so that any new instances are automatically associated with App-SG.
- **Database security group (DB-SG):** This should permit inbound access from App-SG on the appropriate database port (eg 3306). It should be associated with the database.

Please note that **a security group can refer to another security group**. This will permit access from resources associated with the inbound security group, rather than having to specify IP addresses. Any new resources added to a security group (eg a new instance in the Auto Scaling group) will then automatically be included in the access permissions.

Any resources *not* referenced by a security group will be denied inbound access by default.